# how to insert image instead of nav menu component

Tags: html, css

My piece of code html looks like this

```
<nav>
  
    <li><span><a href="">About</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="">Work</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="">History</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="" class="button">Contact</a></span></li>
    
</nav>
```

so I want to replace this menu component with some Svg images. I try just open div tag inside 'li', 'span' like everywhere but is does not work what I have to do?

Comment: where exactly you want to insert image your question is not clear enough

Comment: instead of "about", "work" and "history"

Comment: note you have an invalid markup. `<li>` can only be child elements of `<ul>`, `<ol>` and `<menu>`. In you case you should go for `<menu>`

Comment: can U make it in piece of code please? as I guess will i change nav tag with menu tag?

Comment: are you using images or SVG icons, are you using an external icons library such as fontawesome or you have your own svg included in your project folder?

Comment: no not swapt he tags just add them: `<nav><menu><li>...</li><li>...</li></menu></nav>`

Answer (score 1):

You're syntax is wrong. `<li>` has to be nested inside either `<ul>`, `<ol>` or `<menu>`. You can choose whichever one you want, but I think that your situation might work the best with `<menu>`.

```html
<nav>
  <menu>
    <li><span><a href="">About</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="">Work</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="">History</a></span></li>
    <li><span><a href="" class="button">Contact</a></span></li>
  </menu> 
</nav>
```

Now, the rest depends on what SVG you're talking about, are you using an SVG icon that you have included in your project folder or you're importing and external library like *fontawesome* icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the text links in your navigation menu with SVG by using img tag within  a tag. Make sure to specify the source of the SVG image using the src attribute and add class to the img tag to style it.

```
    <nav>   
        <li><span><a href=""><img src="svg.svg" class="menu-icon"></img></a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href=""><img src="work.svg" class="menu-icon"></img></a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href=""><img src="history.svg" class="menu-icon"></img></a></span></li>
        <li><span><a href=""><img src="contact.svg" class="menu-icon"></img></a></span></li>
        
    </nav>
```